# JavaScript regex to remove capitals, but keep all-uppercase words?

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, how would I turn the string

```
  "Hello World FOOBAR"
```

into

```
  "hello world FOOBAR"
```

i.e. removing word capitalization but keeping all-upper-case words as they are?

Thanks! (Background: We have an all-caps pixel font where upper-case is converted into bold to indicate emphasis, but when someone types a merely first-letter-capitalized word, they likely don't intend emphasis)

Comment: a single regular expression is not appropriate for this problem, but you should also formally define what you consider to be an "all-upper-case word". Does "A" count? What about "YEE-HAW"? How do you delineate words?

Comment: And what about "HEllo"?

Comment: also, using case for emphasis seems silly when you could just use an `<em>` element. Can't you parse this stuff once on the server and store it correctly?

Comment: For the scope of this question, single letters (say "I") would also be lower-cased as emphasis intent cannot be derived well from them. Other fringe issues can be ignored and fall back to either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can work:

```
s = "I Hello World FOOBAR";
r = s.replace(/(\b[A-Z])(?![A-Z])/g, function($1) { return $1.toLowerCase(); });
//=> i hello world FOOBAR
```

Comment: Edit: Great! Is there a way to exclude single-letter words like "I"?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to ask: Is there a way to exclude single-letter words like "I"?

Comment: It already excludes single letter words. So `I Hello World FOOBAR` becomes `I hello world FOOBAR` is that not what you want?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant: to exclude them from being emphasized, in other words, to include them being lower cased :) (As with single-letter words the emphasis intent is not clearly deducable)

Comment: OK check update now. Going offline now. Will check again in the morning.